# logcat gives empty buffer

Tags: android, logcat

I run:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
BufferedReader buffuerReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

in order to read `logcat`, but somehow it returns an empty buffer:

[image: bufferReader]

A look inside `buf`:

[image: empty buf]

(it's empty)

Note that in eclipse it's not empty. Also, if I run `logcat -d` from the `adb shell` (i.e in cmd: `adb shell logcat -d`) it is also not empty.

Answer (score 0):

I was just working on something similar and I found that since JellyBean you will need root access or the permission `android.permission.READ_LOGS`, which is only grantable to system apps on a regular device, in order to read log files outside the adb.

So if/once you have a rooted device you can:

1) Add the permission in your manifest and use the adb shell to grant the permission with the command:

`pm grant <package name> android.permission.READ_LOGS`

Note that you might need to restart the application after granting the permission.

2) Use `su` when you execute the command to run it as root:

`Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su logcat -d");`

Using one of these two methods you should be able to get the output from the logcat command. I used the latter aproach in my application and it works for me.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This answer looks legit. I haven't tried it yet because I found a workaround before I read it. I'll surely give it a try sometime later though!
The workaround is creating a file appender in `logback.xml` and just reading from it instead of logcat.